# I'm trying to write a discord bot in python but my code is not working

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to code my first discord bot in python and I need a bit of help with this piece of code, keep in mind im new to python and I started learning about 2 weeks ago.

```
    @bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content
    author = message.author
    if content == "example yes":
        bot.say("example @%s" % (author))
```

I want the bot to write "example2 @user" if a user says "example yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not `await`ing `bot.say`, and that's not how you mention a user (you use the  [`User.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.mention) attribute instead)

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content
    author = message.author
    if content == "example yes":
        await bot.say("example {}".format(author.mention))
```

Comment: And can you please tell me what does the await do in the sixth line of the code.

Comment: `await` says that your code is going to wait for a coroutine to finish, but it's okay if other code runs in the meantime.  It was introduced in [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/).  If that's a little too much of a technical document, I recommend searching for Python tutorials covering coroutines, async, and await.  See also [Tasks and Coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) from the documentation.